# get value from nested object by key | refactoring 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, object, refactoring

I have below method where i get value from the nested object , want to refactor it to best possible way but cannot use Object.hasOwnProperty because of linting rules

```
export const getValueFromNestedObject = (obj = {}, key = '') => {
    let result;
    for (let i = 0; i< Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
        if (typeof obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]] === 'object') {
            result = getValueFromNestedObject(obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]], key);
            if(typeof result != 'undefined') {
                return result;
            }
        } else if (Object.keys(obj)[i] === key) {
            return obj[key];
        }
    }
}


const valueObj = {
    '@close' : {
        'type': 'button',
        'dom' : {
            'data-linkName' : 'Close'
        }
    },
    '@popupText': {
        'type': 'HTML',
        'options': {
            'html': 'Pop Up Text that is required as result'
            'label': 'Heads Up'
        }
    }
};

const key = 'html';
console.log(getValueFromNestedObject(valueObj, key));
expect(getValueFromNestedObject(valueObj, key)).toEqual('Pop Up Text that is required as result')
```

Comment: One optimization would be to cache the results of `Object.keys(obj)` at the top of your function. As it stands, you are calling it three times for each iteration in each call, whereas you could optimize it to only be called once per call.

Comment: Too bad you don't want to use `hasOwnProperty`... I think for a recursive object search, that is sort of exactly what you want. If you get passed something with a complicated prototype chain (or worse, a property loop), this method will be no good. What improvements were you looking for in your refactor?

Comment: There is no point to define default key argument (key = ' '). Don't start looping if there is no key.